# Insert tag if and only if it does not exist

Tags: xslt

I would like to do an XSLT transformation on an XML file ensuring that tag `<B>` is inserted into tag `<A>` if and only if it is not there. Example:

```
<A>foo</A> should become <A><B>foo</B></A>
<A>foo <x>bar</x></A> should become <A><B>foo <x>bar</x></B></A>
<A><B>foo</B></A> should remain <A><B>foo</B></A>
<A><B>foo <x>bar</x></B></A> should remain <A><B>foo <x>bar</x></B></A>
```

Hence `<B>` should be inserted if and only if it is "missing".
How do I do that?

Edit (clarification in response to comment):

```
<A>xxx <B>yyy</B></A> should become <A><B>xxx <B>yyy</B></B></A>
<A><B>xxx</B> yyy</A> should become <A><B><B>xxx</B> yyy</B></A>
```

I.e., `<A>` should always have one and only one child, which is a `<B>`, and nothing should be done if this requirement is fulfilled already.

Comment: "*if and only if it is not there*" "Is there" is not a good enough definition.  For example, what about `<A>foo <B>bar</B> foobar</A>` or  `<A><x><B>foo</B></x></A>`?

Comment: I have edited the question. That was not clear, indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<A>` should always have one and only one child, which is a `<B>`

Then you are really looking for `A` that has no childen nodes or has a child node other than `B` or has more than one `B` children:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="A[not(node()) or node()[not(self::B)] or count(B) > 1]">
    <A>
        <B>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </B>
    </A>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input**

```
<root>
    <A/>
    <A>foo</A>
    <A>foo <x>bar</x></A>
    <A><B>foo</B></A>
    <A><B>foo <x>bar</x></B></A>
    <A>xxx <B>yyy</B></A>
    <A><B>xxx</B> yyy</A>
    <A><B>foo</B><B>bar</B></A>
</root>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <A>
      <B/>
   </A>
   <A>
      <B>foo</B>
   </A>
   <A>
      <B>foo <x>bar</x>
      </B>
   </A>
   <A>
      <B>foo</B>
   </A>
   <A>
      <B>foo <x>bar</x>
      </B>
   </A>
   <A>
      <B>xxx <B>yyy</B>
      </B>
   </A>
   <A>
      <B>
         <B>xxx</B> yyy</B>
   </A>
   <A>
      <B>
         <B>foo</B>
         <B>bar</B>
      </B>
   </A>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you. Runs perfectly and saved me hours of work!

Answer (score 2):

We may have to adjust depending upon how you resolve the ambiguity pointed out by @michael.hor257k, but this handles one reasonable interpretation of your requirements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="A[not(B)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <B>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </B>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given this input XML:

```
<examples>
  <A>foo</A>
  <A>foo <x>bar</x></A>
  <A><B>foo</B></A>
  <A><B>foo <x>bar</x></B></A>
</examples>
```

It produces this output XML:

```
<examples>
  <A><B>foo</B></A>
  <A><B>foo <x>bar</x></B></A>
  <A><B>foo</B></A>
  <A><B>foo <x>bar</x></B></A>
</examples>
```

---

**Update per update to question:**

> `<A>` should always have one and only one child, which is a `<B>`, and
>   nothing should be done if this requirement is fulfilled already.

**Ok, then change the above template match from**

```
  <xsl:template match="A[not(B)]">
```

**to**

```
  <xsl:template match="A[not(B) or count(node()) > 1]">
```

**Then given this new input XML:**

```
<examples>
  <A>foo</A>
  <A>foo <x>bar</x></A>
  <A><B>foo</B></A>
  <A><B>foo <x>bar</x></B></A>
  <A>xxx <B>yyy</B></A>
  <A><B>xxx</B> yyy</A>
</examples>
```

**The new XSLT will produce this new output XML**

```
<examples>
  <A><B>foo</B></A>
  <A><B>foo <x>bar</x></B></A>
  <A><B>foo</B></A>
  <A><B>foo <x>bar</x></B></A>
  <A><B>xxx <B>yyy</B></B></A>
  <A><B><B>xxx</B> yyy</B></A>
</examples>
```

**as requested.**